# JQuery how to pass space in value?

Tags: jquery, load, space

I am working with jquery I am passing values one page to another page via load() function and I am insert that all data from that page. but if in value space will come then every thing is going to be 0 would you please help me?

Comment: You'll need to clarify, I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "everything is going to be 0"?

Comment: Could you please post the source code? KTHXBYE

Answer (score 0):

**IF** what you need is to remove white spaces:

```
var result = "here we have white spaces".replace(/\s/g, "");
alert(result)​ // herewehavewhitespaces
```